# In a triangle what is the minimum value of $ \frac{a}{c+a-b} + \frac{b}{a+b-c} + \frac{c}{b+c-a} $

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, optimization, triangles

The given question was,

> In a triangle what is the minimum value of $ \displaystyle \frac{a}{c+a-b} + \frac{b}{a+b-c} + \frac{c}{b+c-a}? $

The answer for this question was found to be $3$. I tried by rationalising the denomination and using the law of cosines. I will show simplification for the first term,
$$ \displaystyle \frac{a}{c+a-b} = \frac{a \cdot (c+a+b)}{(c+a)^2-b^2} = \frac{c+a+b}{2c(1+ \cos{B})} $$
And I was stuck here. I have no ideas for proceeding further. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated or any other process would be appreciated.

Comment: The way you have shown, won't we be able to take $\dfrac{\text{perimeter}}{2}$ common? Then the answer is going to be dependent on the $\text{perimeter}$ since the remaining function is independent of $\text{perimeter}$ and the term won't be cancelling out.

Comment: Something is wrong with your calculation; the LHS is unitless but the RHS has units of length...

Comment: I have edited it now

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3626167/42969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $a, b, c$ are the side lengths of a triangle, we can write $x = b + c - a$, $y = c + a - b$, $z = a + b - c$.

Then $x, y, z$ are positive numbers and we have $a = \frac{y + z}2$ etc.

This transforms the original formula to $$\frac 12\left(\frac{y + z}y + \frac{z + x}z + \frac{x + y}x\right) = \frac12\left(3 + \frac z y + \frac x z + \frac y x\right)$$ and it suffices to show that $\frac z y + \frac x z + \frac y x\geq 3$ for positive numbers $x, y, z$. This is simply the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Comment: Nice answer :-)